# RegEx - How to match a string without a ']' in front or '[' after it?

Tags: regex

match [ABC][BBC] without a ']' in front of it or '[' afterwards

"][ABC][BBC]" -> fail

"Crap[ABC][BBC]Blah sth else" -> Match

"[Crap][ABC][BBC]balsh sth " -> fail

"[ABC][BBC][Crap]" -> fail

"[ABC][BBC]Blah [ABC][BBC]XD" -> match both

Answer (score 1):

Use [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<!\])\[ABC\]\[BBC\](?!\[)
```

Answer (score -1):

Formula:

```
[^\]](\[ABC\]\[BBC\])[^\[]
```

[Test](https://regex101.com/r/WkerOU/1)